# Android Things with Xamarin Issue with IGpioCallback

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-things

I'm just starting with Android Things with Xamarin, and I've already successfully turned on a LED, but I'm having trouble to detect a push button input.
I think the problem is the `"RegisterGpioCallback"` in the code below, but I'm not sure and really don't know how to fix it. Can somebody help me?? This is the code I'm using:

```
public class BlinkActivity : Activity
{
    private IGpio gpio;
    private IGpio button;
    private IGpioCallback mButtonCallback;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        this.mButtonCallback = mButtonCallback; 
        PeripheralManager peripheralManager = PeripheralManager.Instance;
        gpio = peripheralManager.OpenGpio("BCM17");
        gpio.SetDirection(Gpio.DirectionOutInitiallyLow);
        gpio.Value = false;
        button = peripheralManager.OpenGpio("BCM4");
        button.SetDirection(Gpio.DirectionIn);
        button.SetEdgeTriggerType(Gpio.EdgeNone);
        button.RegisterGpioCallback(new Handler(), mButtonCallback);
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (mButtonCallback.OnGpioEdge(button) == true)
            {
                gpio.Value = !gpio.Value;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually implement the `IGpioCallback` interface so the `com.google.android.things.pio` library can make a "call back" into your application when the value of the GPIO changes.

Assign the `RegisterGpioCallback` to the actual object instance that has implemented the interface, in the following example, that will be on the `Activity`.

```
public class BlinkActivity : Activity, IGpioCallback
{
    ~~~~
    button.RegisterGpioCallback(new Handler(), this);
    ~~~~

    // remove the Task.Run block

    public OnGpioEdge(Gpio gpio)
    {
        Log.Debug("SO", gpio.Value.ToString());
    }

    ~~~~
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues following this in Maui. I'd created an IGPIO interface in the shared code, and then a platform-specific GPIO class inside the Android platform code. The code would run, but then crash when it got to the Registration of the callback. The error said I had to pass a Java.Lang.Object or Java.Lang.Throwable as argument 2 to com.google.android.things.pio.impl.GpioImpl.registerGpioCallback(android.os.Handler, com.google.android.things.pio.GpioCallback).

I tried using each of these as the base class for my GPIO class, but then the app wouldn't build. When I'd autogenerated the IGpioCallback interface implementation in the class it had created a dispose method and a Handle property along with the OnGpioEdge callback method. Removing these allowed the app to work properly. so my class definition ended up looking something like this for the registration and event:

```
public class GPIO : Java.Lang.Throwable, IGPIO, IGpioCallback
{
    public event EventHandler OnButtonEdge;
    IGpio ButtonPin;

    public void registerPinForEdgeDetection(string pinName)
    {
        using (var peripheralManager = PeripheralManager.Instance)
        {
            ButtonPin = peripheralManager?.OpenGpio(pinName);
            ButtonPin.SetDirection(Gpio.DirectionIn);
            ButtonPin.SetEdgeTriggerType(Gpio.EdgeBoth);
            ButtonPin.RegisterGpioCallback(new Android.OS.Handler(), this);
        }

    }

    public bool OnGpioEdge(IGpio gpio)
    {
        OnButtonEdge?.Invoke(ButtonPin, EventArgs.Empty);
        return true;
    }

}
```